# Как определить, чем является инфинитив: подлежащим или сказуемым?

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор, подлежащее

Например:

**Работать совместно.**

"Работать" - это подлежащее или сказуемое. Мне, кажется, это сказуемое. Хотел узнать ваше мнение!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что это **словосочетание, а не предложение**.

Пример предложения:  **Необходимо работать** совместно. Предложение безличное, инфинитив входит в составное глагольное сказуемое *необходимо работать*.

Или: *Работать* совместно ― вот наша задача. Здесь *работать* ― это подлежащее.